# boost 1.58 xpressive::sregex outputs errors in debug mode

Tags: boost, xpressive

I encountered some problems when using boost::xpressive of boost1.58 on Visual C++ 2013.

My test program that using below code spills errors like below.

> *This error  does not occur on Release mode.*

*Is this a boost's bug?*

```
sregex reg = sregex::compile("\\");
```

**Error:**

> e:\dev\vs2013projects\sandbox\sandbox\sandbox.cpp(35) : see reference
>   to function template instantiation
>   'boost::xpressive::basic_regex>>>
>   boost::xpressive::basic_regex>>>::compile(const
>   char
>   *,boost::xpressive::basic_regex>>>::flag_type)'
>   being compiled 1>
>   e:\dev\vs2013projects\sandbox\sandbox\sandbox.cpp(35) : see reference
>   to class template instantiation
>   'boost::xpressive::basic_regex>>>'
>   being compiled

Comment: on a unrelated (I think) note: that's not a valid regex. A \ escape requires a following character. To match a single \ char, use `"\\\\"` or `"\\x5c"`

Comment: Alternatively, `R"(\\)"`. Works much better the more you would have to otherwise escape.